# length of an interval as a limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I$ be an interval and $A_{n}$ be the set of $k/n$ where $k$ is an integer.

Prove that the length of $I$ (the positive difference between the end points) is the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of $\frac{1}{n}|(I \cap A_{n})|$.

My plan was to split it up into cases for the different type of intervals and come up with formulas for $|(I \cap A_{n})|$, but I'm finding that very tricky.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: how different can $|I|$ be from $|IA_n|$ (as a function of $n$)? You should be able to find a bound that goes to $0$ as $n$ gets large

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'different'. I tried for a while playing with different combinations but couldn't come up with a pattern

Comment: I meant the length of $I$ and the length of the intersection.  I updated to say that.  The difference is the "two ends" of $I$ that "hang over".  How long can they be?

Comment: How would I work that out?

Comment: Is it (b-a)/n ?

Comment: What are $b$ and $a$?  They have not been defined.  Let's take an example:  Let $I=(0.20001, 0.45)$  I suggest you compute $IA_n|$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and think about how much of $I$ is not covered in $|IA_n|$ at each step.

Comment: I'm really trying. Its driving me nuts actually. I couldn't get anywhere with the concrete example. So I'm trying to think like this. If $I=(a,b)$ then $b$ won't be in the intersection if $b>b/n$ so the most it can miss the intersection by is.. but that's not right is it. Also, how will finding this difference help. I'm very confused, please help me a bit more

Comment: On the right, $I$ can only extend beyond $IA_n$ by at most $\frac 1n$ and the same on the left. So $|I|-|IA_n| \lt \frac 2n$

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been very clear. $|IA_{n}|$ is the cardinality of $IA_{n}$. How does this change things? Thanks and sorry about not being clear

Comment: I was assuming $|IA_n|$ was the length of the interval from the lowest point of $A_n$ that is part of $I$ to the highest, but it still works.  If the length of $I$ is $x$, there will be at least $\lfloor nx \rfloor$ points within it and at most one more.  Because of the factor $\frac 1n$, the error of $\pm 1$ goes to zero.

Comment: How is it $nx$? I  consider the example $(0,4)$ with $N=2$, I have $ \{ \frac12, \frac22, \frac32, \frac42, \frac52, \frac62, \frac72 \}$ which is seven points..

Comment: Wouldn't the number of points change depending on whether you are using closed, open interval etc

Comment: @Buraian:  it can change by at most two if both endpoints are in $A_n$.  That makes the change in the final result at most $\frac 2n$, which goes to zero, so it doesn't matter what kind of interval you use.